# How to use the Tshark editcap function with Pyshark (for splitting or filtering files based on time range)

Tags: python, wireshark, pcap, tshark, pyshark

I am analysing existing PCAP files with Pyshark in Python.

I want to write a function that splits/filters the PCAP file based on time range. I would like to use the Tshark editcap function to split the captured files.

1. Does anyone know if I can use the Tshark editcap function in a python script?
2. If not: can anyone come up with an elegant way for splitting/filtering files based on time range?